# Can't get mailto tag to work in my website in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, email, mailto

In my website, I have a textarea and a button, and I want to receive an email whose body is the text written in the textarea box. A button will call a function on click which will send the email. After researching about this I found that people on various forums are suggesting to use the `mailto:` tag. However, when I use the `mailto` tag as in the code below, I don't receive any emails. My relevant code is as below;

HTML:

```
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click ME!</button>
```

Javascript:

```
function myFunction () {
    var x = document.getElementById("text").value;
    document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = x;
    'mailto:' + 'someone@gmail.com' + '?subject=' + Requests + '&body=' + x;
}
```

Comment: Where is my "needs basic understanding" close reason ..?

Comment: You going to look at your answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not reset the href atribute of the document. You simply calculated what that value would be. You need to set the `location.href` to `'mailto:' + 'someone@gmail.com' + '?subject=' + Requests + '&body=' + x;`

```js
function myFunction () {
var x = document.getElementById("text").value;
var url = 'mailto:' + 'someone@gmail.com' + '?subject=' + "Requests" + '&body=' + x;
window.open(url);
document.getElementById("p").href = url;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click ME!</button>
<a id="p">newlink</a>
```

Comment: It may not work in SO snippets. Security and all that. @AncientBehemoth

Comment: And that url in your comment does work. @AncientBehemoth

Answer (score 0):

here an example of how you can do it:

> window.location.href = "mailto:mail@example.org?subject=" + someVar + '&body=' + SomeOtherVar;